# Checking if IX or IV are followed by another character

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an algorithm that is supposed to take a string called `str` and check it against a specific rule defined as:

NOTHING comes after IX or IV.
It will print legal if the rule is not broken, and Illegal if the rule IS broken.

Here is my code that I have created:

```
string str = "MXCIVXX";
int length = str.length();
bool legal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ((str[i] == 'I' && str[i + 1] == 'X') && (str[i + 2] != '/0'))
        legal = false;

    if ((str[i] == 'I' && str[i + 1] == 'V') && (str[i + 2] != '/0'))
        legal = false;
}
if (legal == true)
    cout << "Legal" << endl;
else if (legal == false)
    cout << "Illegal" << endl;
```

I have tested multiple roman numerals in the string but it prints out legal if IX is followed by another character in the string. How can I fix this to confirm that IX or IV is not followed by another character?

Comment: "_NOTHING comes after IX or IV.._"  Define NOTHING, you mean just space? end of line? no other roman numerals?

Comment: Debug it step by step and see why this happens. That is what you are supposed to do when your program doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing as in no other character is to come after it. The last 2 characters are either IX or IV.

Comment: Note that `'/0'` is dramatically different from `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant the null character, so `'\0'` instead of `'/0'`

Also, your approach is not accurate(read the below comments and thanks to [@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver)). This approach should work better:

```
int main() 
{
    std::string str = "IX";
    int size = str.size();
    bool legal = true;


    if (str[size - 2] == 'I') // the char before the last char
    {
        if (str[size - 1] == 'V' || str[size - 1] == 'X') // the last char
            legal = true;
        else
            legal = false;
    }
    else
        legal = false;

    if (legal)
        std::cout << "Legal" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "Illegal" << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string::find` is your friend. You won't need the `str[i]... && str[i+1]...` business.

Comment: This is going to go past then end of the array in a number of cases.

Comment: It will break @nathan. It works with `"MXCIX"` or `"IV"` Could you explain more please?

Comment: UB doesn't have to not work.  It is just a bad idea to have it.  If the string ends with IX or IV then `str[i + 2] != '\0'` is going past the end of the string and is UB.

Comment: The string "IV" only has the valid indexs of 0 and 1.

Comment: I just debugged it covering more cases. It is not giving accurate results and you are right @nathan

Comment: Thanks. Works like it should now.

Comment: @FirstStep I just tested it for my program that needs this algorithm on a larger scale and works for me.

Comment: This now fails a string like "MI" which is legal.

Comment: @zack is "MI" legal?

Comment: @nathan I am not sure if that case in included. OP asked only for `IV` and `IX`

Comment: MMXVI is legal (2016); your code rejects it. `IX` is a shorthand for `VIIII` and `IV` is short for `IIII`. His description only sounds as though he is testing for violation of the rule that you can't have anything after `IX` or `IV`. (`IVI` would be `V`)

Answer (score 1):

To check if "IX" or "IV" exist and if it does it is at then end of the string you can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and check that it returns a position that is at the end of the string.  So if we have a string like

```
std::string bad_str = "MXCIVXX";
```

and we use `find` like

```
std::size_t pos = bad_str.find("IV");
```

Then `pos` will either be `std::string::npos` meaning nothing was found or it will be the position of where it found "IV".  You can check that by using

```
if (pos == std::string::npos || pos == bad_str.size() - 2)
    std::cout << "good\n";
else
    std::cout << "bad\n";
```

Then you just need to do this for "IX" as well.  This avoids all the pitfalls that you could forget to handle in the manual version like going past then end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code which will handle cases like "MIXCIXXIV" :

```
    String str = "MXCIVXX";
    int length = str.length();
    bool legal = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
        if ((str[i] == 'I' && str[i + 1] == 'X') && length > i + 2){
            legal = false;
break;
    }
        if ((str[i] == 'I' && str[i + 1] == 'V') && length > i + 2){
            legal = false;
break;
}
    }
    if (legal == true)
        cout << "Legal" << endl;
    else if (legal == false)
        cout << "Illegal" << endl;
```